# Slider bar show twice into HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html

Working on small calcultion form where user with just drag and drop of slider, can calculate about their earnings. But for some reason, the form is showing twice, and just one of them works. For example:

[image]

First slider not works at all, and dont make calculation, but second one works as should be. So now i want to remove first non working slider. This is entire HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Slider</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://public.mym.fans/design/styles/framework.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.plyr.io/3.4.7/plyr.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.mym.fans/design/scripts/jquery.js?v=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://public.mym.fans/design/scripts/plugins.js?v=3"></script>

</head>

<body>


        <div id="page-content" class="page-content" style="min-height: 561px;">

    <!-- ionrangeSlider -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://public.mym.fans/design/scripts/ion-rangeSlider-220/css/ionrangeSlider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://public.mym.fans/design/scripts/ion-rangeSlider-220/css/ionrangeSliderskinHTML5.css" />

</br>
</br>
</br>
</br>

            <div class="heading-block estimation_rev" style="background-image: url(https://d1yei2z3i6k35z.cloudfront.net/156728/5ea9bab7e6f9b_ADBQnb_t20_4EXQna-min.jpg);">
                <h2 class="thin no-bottom animate-zoom" data-sr-id="14" style="; visibility: visible;  -webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s, opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s; transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s, opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s; ">Estimate your revenue</h2>
                <h5 class="small-text animate-fade" data-sr-id="2" style="; visibility: visible;  -webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; ">Select your number of followers</h5>
                <p class="larger-text thin half-top full-bottom animate-fade" data-sr-id="3" style="; visibility: visible;  -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1); opacity: 1;transform: translateY(0) scale(1); opacity: 1;-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s, opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s; transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s, opacity 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s; ">
                    <span class="irs js-irs-0  irs-with-grid"><span class="irs"><span class="irs-line" tabindex="0"><span class="irs-line-left"></span><span class="irs-line-mid"></span><span class="irs-line-right"></span></span><span class="irs-min" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">0</span><span class="irs-max" style="display: none; visibility: visible;">1</span><span class="irs-from" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span><span class="irs-to" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span><span class="irs-single" style="left: -0.535332%;">100 000 followers</span></span><span class="irs-grid" style="width: 94.2184%; left: 2.79079%;"><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 0%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-0" style="left: 0%; margin-left: -1.17773%;">0</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 20%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 15%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 10%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 5%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 25%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-1" style="left: 25%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.06852%;">250 000</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 45%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 40%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 35%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 30%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 50%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-2" style="left: 50%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.17559%;">500 000</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 70%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 65%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 60%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 55%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 75%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-3" style="left: 75%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.06852%;">750 000</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 95%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 90%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 85%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 80%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 100%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-4" style="left: 100%; margin-left: -4.92505%;">1 000 000</span></span><span class="irs-bar" style="left: 2.89079%; width: 9.42184%;"></span><span class="irs-bar-edge"></span><span class="irs-shadow shadow-single" style="display: none;"></span><span class="irs-slider single" style="left: 9.42184%;"></span></span><input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range" onchange="estimate()" class="irs-hidden-input" tabindex="-1" readonly="">
                </p>
                <h5 class="small-text animate-fade line-height-20" data-sr-id="4" style="; visibility: visible;  -webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out 0s; ">Estimated revenue = between <span class="font-size-20" id="estim_bottom">9000€</span> and <span class="font-size-20" id="estim_top">45000€</span> per month*</h5>
                <div class="overlay dark-overlay"></div>
            </div>

        <div class="footer_condition content">*Based on an average subscription rate between 1% and 5% of your community. Does not include the MYM charge.</div>




        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#range").ionRangeSlider({
                    hide_min_max: true,
                    keyboard: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 1000000,
                    from: 100000,
                    from_min: 5000,
                    step: 10000,
                    postfix: " followers",
                    grid: true
                });
            });
            function estimate()   
                {
                var slider = $("#range").data("ionRangeSlider");
                var from = slider.result.from;
                // Calculer les revenus
                var rev_bottom = Math.round(((from*1)/100)*9);
                $('#estim_bottom').text(rev_bottom+'€');
                var rev_top = Math.round(((from*5)/100)*9);
                $('#estim_top').text(rev_top+'€');
                }
        </script>


    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Some help why is showing second non-workin slider, and how to remove it? Many thanks. This is [site](https://creators.mym.fans/index.php) from where i get that element. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ds3jvnmk/) with code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the HTML code that is being generated by the slider plugin. Remove the HTML and you should be good to go.

Remove this part:

```
<span class="irs js-irs-0  irs-with-grid">
... remove all html inside this
</span>
```

Here is the working snippet

https://jsfiddle.net/9pokrqea/

Comment: Works, but when insert into HTML editor, this line:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://public.mym.fans/design/styles/framework.css">`

causing form do not work. Just that line causing issue. Some help?

Comment: do you mean, you are not able to enter the number in the input?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#range").ionRangeSlider({})
```

Is initializing the object with all necessary html.

Take a look at documentation.

[source](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/start.html)

So instead of the whole `<span>` structure

```html
<p ...>
 <span class="irs js-irs-0  irs-with-grid"><span class="irs"><span class="irs-line" tabindex="0"><span class="irs-line-left"></span><span class="irs-line-mid"></span><span class="irs-line-right"></span></span><span class="irs-min" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">0</span><span class="irs-max" style="display: none; visibility: visible;">1</span><span class="irs-from" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span><span class="irs-to" style="visibility: hidden;">0</span><span class="irs-single" style="left: -0.535332%;">100 000 followers</span></span><span class="irs-grid" style="width: 94.2184%; left: 2.79079%;"><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 0%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-0" style="left: 0%; margin-left: -1.17773%;">0</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 20%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 15%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 10%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 5%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 25%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-1" style="left: 25%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.06852%;">250 000</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 45%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 40%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 35%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 30%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 50%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-2" style="left: 50%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.17559%;">500 000</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 70%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 65%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 60%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 55%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 75%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-3" style="left: 75%; visibility: visible; margin-left: -4.06852%;">750 000</span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 95%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 90%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 85%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol small" style="left: 80%"></span><span class="irs-grid-pol" style="left: 100%"></span><span class="irs-grid-text js-grid-text-4" style="left: 100%; margin-left: -4.92505%;">1 000 000</span></span><span class="irs-bar" style="left: 2.89079%; width: 9.42184%;"></span><span class="irs-bar-edge"></span><span class="irs-shadow shadow-single" style="display: none;"></span><span class="irs-slider single" style="left: 9.42184%;"></span></span><input type="text" id="range" value="" name="range" onchange="estimate()" class="irs-hidden-input" tabindex="-1" readonly="">
                </p>
```

Keep only `input` tag

```html
<p ...>
<input
  type="text"
  id="range"
  value=""
  name="range"
  onchange="estimate()"
  class="irs-hidden-input"
  tabindex="-1"
  readonly=""
/>
</p>
```